# How to fetch path of a file from preference page and print the Output on console via Button on Workbench?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have made one preference page whose programming is:

```
public class SAML
extends FieldEditorPreferencePage
implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage {

public SAML() {
    super(GRID);
    setPreferenceStore(RmpPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());
    setDescription("Browse Appropriate files");
}

public FileFieldEditor f;
public FileFieldEditor f1;
public void createFieldEditors() {
    f=new FileFieldEditor(PreferenceConstants.P_PATH, 
            "&Prism.bat File:", getFieldEditorParent());
    addField(f);

    f1=new FileFieldEditor(PreferenceConstants.P_PATH1, 
            "&NuSMV Application File:", getFieldEditorParent());
    addField(f1);
}
```

I want to get path of `FileFieldEditor f` and want this path to run on a button which is embedded on workbench (but programming of that button is in different project on the same workspace).
The button programming which has hard coded path of "prism.bat" file is:

```
try {
        //to clear the console on every click of button

        IViewPart view = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView(IConsoleConstants.ID_CONSOLE_VIEW);
        if (view != null) {
            (myConsole).clearConsole();
        }           
        ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\prism-4.0\\bin\\prism.bat");
        pb.directory(new File("C:\\Program Files\\prism-4.0\\bin"));
        Process p=pb.start();

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String in;
        while((in = input.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(in);
        }


        int exitVal=p.waitFor();            

       if(exitVal==0)
       {
            out.println("Process Successful");
            out.println("Printing on console with Exitvalue =0");

        }
       else
           {out.println("Process failed");
           out.println("Exitvalue = 1");
           }

    }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

But I want to fetch file from my preference page `FileFieldEditor f` and want this path to embed in button programming so that when button is pressed, result is shown.

Comment: What is it you can't do? You have your `FileFieldEditor`, you have your code with the hard-coded path, it sounds like you just want to replace the hard-coded path with something from the `FileFieldEditor`. So you just need to pass a reference to the `FileFieldEditor` to the code with the path to the .bat file.

Comment: @BalusC - but i am not able to access the fileFieldEditor in the programming of my button. Please let me know, how to access the path from FileFieldEditor and give it as an input to ProcessBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two parts:

- Code that initialize the default for the preference
- Code that use the current value

To set the default, you use the following code in the `Activator`:

```
public class Activator extends AbstractUIPlugin {
    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        super.start(context);
        IPreferenceStore ps = getPreferenceStore();
        ps.setDefault(SHOW_IMAGE, true);
    }
    public static final String SHOW_IMAGE = "showImage";
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences` extension point...

Note that the code above assume that the type of the preference is `Boolean` - there are other methods for numbers, strings, etc... A file name is a string.

To use the current value, just use

```
if (Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore().getBoolean(Activator.SHOW_IMAGE)) {
    …
}
```

The following [slides](http://rcp-company.com/uploads/demos/L0032%20-%20Managing%20User%20Preference.pdf) contains a little more information...

Comment: Madesn - Thank you for the response.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But when i am using this code in my activator class, Every time i open my preference page, It does not opens up and shows an error that preference page cannot be created.
Moreover, Please tell me where should i use the second code? Should i use it in Button programming? or elsewhere..

Comment: I need more context to help you with the exception for the preference page. The second snippet is used for the `Button` - and then use `getString(...)` rather than `getBoolean(...)`.

Comment: @madsen - thank you for the response. please check the context below answered by me. Thank You..

Comment: thank you for the response. please check the context below answered by me. Thank You.